# How to get Exif data from local image using Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, exif

If we have image imageName.jpg in Assets.xcassets and let's put that image in UIImage like this:

```
let imageForExif: UIImage = UIImage(named: "imageName.jpg")!
```

**How we can get (extract) Exif data from imageForExif using Swift?**

Answer (score 3):

Try this...

```
  if let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageForExif, 1.0) {
        let imageCFData = imageData as CFData
        if let cgImage = CGImageSourceCreateWithData(imageCFData, nil), let metaDict: NSDictionary = CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(cgImage, 0, nil) {
            let exifDict: NSDictionary = metaDict.object(forKey: kCGImagePropertyExifDictionary) as! NSDictionary
            print(exifDict)
        }
    }
```

But you may have very limited data available. Hope it helps.